# Can't figure out how to track down an error in $.ajax/PHP/MySQL insert

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, syntax-error

I am having a great amount of difficulty tracking down the cause of an error on an $.ajax/PHP/MySQL database insert.

Here's the jQuery side:

```
function SaveNewBranch(newBranchName, dataString) {
    console.log('In function SaveNewBranch(newBranchName, dataString). Value of
        newBranchName: ' + newBranchName + '. Value of dataString: ' + 
        dataString + '.');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../scripts/branchAdmin.php',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(newBranchID) {

            console.log('from server: ' . newBranchID);

            // Clear the page
            ClearPageForNewSelection();

            PopulateBranchDropdown(newBranchID);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('datastring: ' + dataString);
            alert('An error occurred while attempting to save the branch to the 
                database. jqXHR object: ' + xhr + '. Status: ' + status + '. Error
                message: ' + error + '. An error log with more details has been
                created on the server. If the error persists, contact your site
                administrator.');
        }
    });
} // End Save New Branch
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['newBranchName']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchAddr1']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchAddr2']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchCity']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchState']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchZip']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchPhone']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchFax']) &&
    isset($_POST['newBranchUrl'])) {

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $log->lwrite('name: ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchName']) .
        ', addr1: ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchAddr1']) . ',
        addr2: ' .  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchAddr2']) . ',
        city: ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchCity']) . ',
        state: ' .$_POST['newBranchState'] . ', zip: ' .
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchZip']) . ', phone: ' .
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchPhone']) . ', fax: ' . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchFax']) . ', url: ' . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchUrl']));

    $_POST['newBranchState'] == '0' ? $newBranchState = '' : $newBranchState = 
        strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchState']));

    $queryInsertNewBranch = "INSERT INTO branches (name, address1, address2, city, 
        state, zipCode, phone, fax, url) VALUES ('" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchName']) . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchAddr1']) . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchAddr2']) . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchCity']) . "', '" .
        newBranchState . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchZip']) . 
        "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchPhone']) . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchFax']) . "', '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['newBranchUrl']) . "')";

    $log->lwrite('new branch insert: ' . $queryInsertNewBranch);

    $resultInsertNewBranch = @mysqli_query($dbc, $queryInsertNewBranch);
    ...
```

I've confirmed that good data is getting passed to the php script via the console output of "dataString".

Output to the console for a test insert:

```
newBranchName: A Test Branch, datastring: newBranchName=A Test branch&
    newBranchAddr1=123 StateSt.&newBranchAddr2=#123&
    newBranchCity=Anywhere&newBranchState=MN&newBranchZip=12343&
    newBranchPhone=555-555-1212&newBranchFax=555-555-2121&newBranchUrl=minnesota
```

I also confirmed that the php script is getting good data by checking the first $log->lwrite line in the php script.

Output to the log for the same insert test:

```
new branch insert: INSERT INTO branches (name, address1, address2, city, state,
    zipCode, phone, fax, url) VALUES ('A Test Branch', '123 State St.', '#123',
    'Anywhere', 'MN', '12343', '555-555-1212', '555-555-2121', 'minnesota')
```

The last $log->lwrite entry (new branch insert) NEVER gets written to the log file.

Also on the jQuery side the error function is getting fired, displaying the alert box. The values of the three objects there are:

```
jqXHR object: [object Object]
Status: parsererror
Message: Unexpected token e
```

No matter what I enter into the form that takes the data, I always get the same result: the INSERT never runs and the alert box in the error function shows - with the same message every time.

I've gone over and over many times looking at every detail of the code, looking for an erroneous space or single quote where a double quote should be, etc. And I can't for the life of me find what the issue is!

If the jqXHR object may hold a clue, I don't know how to get the elements of that. How do you do that?

I (and my client) would be IMMENSELY appreciative of any help I could get in figuring this out!

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Inspect the response text with your browser developer tool.

Comment: remove  @ from php so you can see the errors , and i jquery part how is dataString formated

Comment: Have you tried running the new branch insert mysql query manually? It might just be a mysql error.

Comment: I think you need to url-escape your dataString variable.  In your print-out there are spaces and periods in the middle of your serialized data.

Comment: @ddjikic, I did remove them at one point, thinking the same thing, but the problem is, it's not getting to those lines with @ symnbols to be able to display the errors. Remember, the last $log line never get written.

Comment: @Keeleon, yes, I did do that, and it inserted fine...

Comment: @Jack, I'm using chrome. I use the console and element inspector all the time, but don't know how to look at the response text. How do you do that?

Comment: It's in the Network tab.

Comment: @AustinMullins, I understand what you mean, but the same thing happens when there are no spaces in any of the fields.

Comment: if juqery return you this jqXHR object: [object Object]
Status: parsererror
Message: Unexpected token e then you shoud first chek why .... to you datastring that youare sending look like this  data:{ name:inputTitle, text:textvar },

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why, but this is what was causing the issue (perhaps someone could enlighten me as why this broke the insert):

When adding the code to my question, I removed a line that I thought wasn't relevant to the question anyway.

The line is this:

```
echo 'new branch state: ' . $newBranchState;
```

And it was immediately after the ternary operator line setting the $newBranchState variable (which does work).

Commenting that echo line out resolved the issue.

Now, can someone please tell me why that would cause the rest of the script to break and give me that error? I see now where the "Unexpected token e" was coming from, but there's a semicolon at the end of the line preceding that echo, so I don't understand why that would cause a problem...